# Mercurial on IIS6+Win Server 2003 - path problems

Tags: iis-6, mercurial, hgweb

I'm trying to get Mercurial going with IIS6 on Windows Server 2003 following the tutorial [on this blog](http://vampirebasic.blogspot.com/2009/06/running-mercurial-on-windows.html)

My setup is

c:\inetpub\HG_web_interface\

and the folder containing repositories is in

d:\HG_repo\

My hgweb.config looks like this

```
[paths]
test = D:\HG_rep\**

[web]
style = monoblue
```

I tried pretty much every combination of forward/backward slashes, no slashed and whatnot, the only way I get it to work is to put my repository in the c: drive, then it works like a charm by simply putting this n hgweb.config

```
[paths]
test = \HG_rep\**

[web]
style = monoblue
```

Any idea on what's wrong?

p.s.: could it be some weird permission problem? If so, how can I troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out: the user configured in the IIS application pool didn't have read/write access to the repository folder!

Sometimes things are much easier than we think... Now I'm trying to troubleshoot why I can't connect to my repository with TortoiseHG...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the "`:`" is interpreted by the [configparser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html).

Can you try to escape it ? A newer hg version should solve it too, since it includes it's own configuration file parser.